# DHCP server installation error Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt

I am trying to install DHCP server using command "sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server". But I got an error. It seems like the mirrored file no longer available.

```
Err http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main isc-dhcp-server i386 4.1.ESV-R4-0ubuntu5.6
404  Not Found

Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/isc-dhcp/isc-dhcp-server_4.1.ESV-R4-0ubuntu5.6_i386.deb 404  Not Found
```

How can I fix the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open a terminal and type;

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

If the problem still continues I'm suggesting you to change your mirror.
Open `source.list` using your text editor. eg; **vim**.

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then locate `http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` and replace it with `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`.

There is a GUI solution called **Software-Sources** for suggestion that is above.
For more information; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Also you can manually download `isc-dhcp-server` package and install it.